# Just getting one field from firestore expo react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, expo, geolocation

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firestore with the code below, but I only get one result. When I eliminate that document, I get the other document with the same query. I don't know what else to do.

```
  const retrieveNetwork2 = async () => {
    const query = geocollection.near({
      center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(15.5, -90.25),
      radius: 1000,
    });

    await query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        let workingX = doc.data().name;

        setReada(workingX);
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for each document that you get back, you call `setReada`. So at the end of processing all documents, `setReada` will only know about the last document in the results.

It's hard to say what exactly you need to change without seeing your `setReada`, but it'll typically be something like:

```
query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  let results = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data().name);
  setReada(results);
});
```

So with this your `setReada` is now an array with the `name` value of each document.

Comment: Hi. It works! Thank you so much! You don't know how much you help me.